# Knowing when to stop burning

Tags: orbit, attitude, measurement, flight-control, velocity

Navigating in orbit usually relies on firing engines for some amount of time to achieve a specific velocity. [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30309), for example, mentions "closed-loop guidance" for the ISS boosting.

1. **How is the initial velocity of the spacecraft usually measured?** Is it estimated from the known orbital parameters? Is it corrected for perturbations and drag, in the case of LEO?
2. **How is initial attitude measured?** Is a [star tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_tracker) used, or other optical measurements from the spacecraft? Or is it mostly ground-based?
3. **How is the ongoing change in velocity measured**? I suspect a [IMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) is only part of the answer here, due to integration errors?

---

Notes:

I'm mostly interested in both stable orbits and transfer orbits around earth and other bodies, not so much the initial launch (which is tracked from ground based radar, as I understand?)

Comment: related: [How is rocket engine cutoff controlled?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7894/195)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it worked for the Space Shuttle, it was fairly autonomous.

[image]

> To perform insertion, orbit, and deorbit maneuvers, there must be
> accurate data for the orbiter's location and velocity with respect to
> the Earth for use by guidance and control. This is the task of the
> shuttle navigation software. The navigation software maintains
> an accurate estimate of the orbiter’s inertial  position and velocity
> in the form of a seven-element “state vector.”
>
> ...
>
> During accelerated flight, the IMUs supply the information to
> calculate this vector. The onboard vector may be updated or replaced
> by the ground with a vector based on data obtained from tracking
> devices.

...

> Because the vehicle's location changes with respect to the Earth as it
> orbits, the state vector is constantly changing, and nav is
> continually having to recompute it. This is done in the General
> Purpose Computers (GPCs) via an algorithm known as “super-g
> navigation.”
>
> The Super-g Algorithm performs the following functions:

> a. Given the
> state vector and gravitational acceleration from the last cycle, a new
> position vector is estimated using either modeled drag acceleration or
> IMU-sensed acceleration.

> b. The gravity at the new position is
> calculated.

> c. Using the change in gravity from the
> past to the current cycle, the position and velocity vectors are
> recomputed.

...

> The flight controllers in the Mission Control Center (MCC) have the
> capability to monitor the onboard state vector as computed by nav. In
> addition, they can monitor tracking data from ground-based radar and
> other external sources. By comparing the two, they can see what sort
> of errors are accumulating. Errors in the onboard state vector are
> inherent in the propagation scheme and grow with time, following a
> fairly predictable pattern. MCC evaluates these errors and may uplink
> a correction factor called a “delta state update” (if in powered
> flight) or a new state vector (if in coasting flight) into the system.

IMU - Inertial Measurement Unit

Everything from *Guidance and Control
Insertion/Orbit/Deorbit Workbook* (not currently online AFAIK)